# ClosedXMLでExcelファイルを印刷する事はできるのか。

Tags: c#

[ClosedXML本家のサイト](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)(を見てみたのですが、Printout的なメソッドがありません。

やはりClosedXMLにはPrintメソッドが存在しないのでしょうか。
または別の方法で実現する事ができるのでしょうか。

どなたかご教授いただけると大変助かります。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/73083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ClosedXMLはファイル操作を行うだけで、画面やプリンターへの描画機能は有していません。さらには[Evaluating Formulas](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml/wiki/Evaluating-Formulas#very-important)には

> Not all formulas are included and you'll probably get a nasty error if the formula isn't supported or if there's an error in the formula.

とあり、数式の計算結果がExcelと一致するとは限りません。

Comment: 質問に関係ないですが、2つのサイトに投稿する事をマルチポストといってマナー違反なんですね…汗　以後気をつけます。　回答ありがとうございました。